# css for all devices or a css for individual devices

Tags: html, css

I am just wondering what is the best approach for web development for across all devices. 
I just want to know if it is better to have 1 css file for all devices or a css file for individual devices?

Because of http 2 it can load multiple files on one TCP connection rather than using multiple connection which http 1.1 did.

The reason why I am asking this question is that when you go into amazon or linkedIn for example (even stack over flow). if you click "inspect" the site,  click on "toggle device toolbar" and using an iphoneX or galaxy s9 setting (for example again). Hit refresh and turn "toggle device toolbar" off.

You would notice that the css looks like its still remembers the mobile phone as if they detect the device and load a css for that device rather than having a single css that fits for all device.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to create a completely different design for seperate devices (meaning your site is somewhat complex, and even then not always the best idea), you should not think of designing for "devices" but rather device attributes like screen sizes, which is done via [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). These can all be in the same CSS file, or you can [split them](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-blocking-css) into separate files to improve load time.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, i just thought it was strange when i tested it out in the developer tool on chrome. I thought it might be the "new thing" to follow through with css styling for device.